# Making GsonRequest to accept empty list or null array

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a Json data to be pulled from a server. This data contains several objects and arrays.

The first model is as follows:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "17",
      "name": "Accessories",
      "child": [
        {
          "id": "371",
          "name": "Belt"
        },
        {
          "id": "55",
          "name": "Derp"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, some of the `results` array doesn't have `child` array. Instead, it have a String with an empty value.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "19",
      "name": "Stuff",
      "child": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

When the code is executed, it returns this line:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
```

This is how the Model looks like:

```
public class CategoryModel {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String category_id;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<CategoryChildModel> child;

    ...
}
```

And this is how I implement the GsonRequest (which using Volley as background asynctask):

```
private void loadCategory() {
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

    String url = Constants.CATEGORIES_LIST;

    GsonRequest<CategoryContainer> myReq = new GsonRequest<CategoryContainer>(
            Request.Method.GET, url, CategoryContainer.class,
            createMyReqSuccessListener(), createMyReqErrorListener());

    mRequestQueue.add(myReq);
}
```

So, anyone knows how to make null object pass through GsonRequest?

Comment: I think you should better tell your server manager or backend engineer not to send the data like this. They should either not send the child at all or send it as null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually your json response should return an empty array not a string for null cases. But if you don't have an option to change server's response then you may try to write a custom json deserializer:

```
class ChildDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<ChildHolder> {
    @Override
    public ChildHolder deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String currentValueOfChild = json.toString();
        Log.d("ChildDeserializer", "ChildDeserializer: child=" + currentValueOfChild);

        ChildHolder childHolder = null;
        if (json instanceof JsonArray) {
            Log.d("ChildDeserializer", "ChildDeserializer: We have an array for 'child'");

            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Child>>() {}.getType();

            JsonArray jsonArray= json.getAsJsonArray();

            childHolder = new ChildHolder();
            childHolder.childList = context.deserialize(jsonArray, listType);
        }

        return childHolder;
    }
}
```

Your response java model should look like below:

```
class Response {
    List<Result> results;
}

class Result {
    private String id, name;
    private ChildHolder child;
}

class ChildHolder {
    private List<Child> childList;
}

class Child {
    private String id, name;
}
```

Apply deserializer while parsing json to java model:

```
String jsonTest1 = "{\"results\":[{\"id\":\"17\",\"name\":\"Accessories\",\"child\":[{\"id\":\"371\",\"name\":\"Belt\"},{\"id\":\"55\",\"name\":\"Derp\"}]}]}";
String jsonTest2 = "{\"results\":[{\"id\":\"19\",\"name\":\"Stuff\",\"child\":\"\"}]}";

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(ChildHolder.class, new ChildDeserializer());

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Response response1 = gson.fromJson(jsonTest1, Response.class);
Response response2 = gson.fromJson(jsonTest2, Response.class);
```

Also please [read this link](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, I'm not really sure what to put in the `deserialize()` method; `// TODO parse json and fill the childList` Could you please guide me a bit on how to fill the childList?

Comment: Do I still need to use `createMyReqSuccessListener()` as the success listener or use the Deserialization instead?

Answer (score 1):

Another option for writing a custom serializer is to simply convert the empty string to an empty array in the JSON. Then your class can remain the way it is:

```
class ChildDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<CategoryModel>
{
    @Override
    public ChildHolder deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
                                   JsonDeserializationContext context) 
                                       throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject obj = json.getAsObject();
        JsonElement e = obj.get("child");
        if (e.isJsonPrimitive()) // it's a String
        {
            obj.remove("child");
            obj.add("child", new JsonArray());
        }

        return new Gson().fromJson(obj, CategoryModel.class);
    }
}
```