# Loop through JSON keys to get values

Tags: java, android

I have a JSON response in this format:

```
{"success":false,"errors":{"one":["First", "Second",...],"two":["First", "Second",...],...}}
```

The `errors` object can have multiple keys where each key can have one or more values.

How can I loop through the keys (in Java) and get their values?

My current code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

String success = obj.getString("success"); // get success
JSONObject errors = obj.getJSONObject("errors"); // get errors
```

Comment: If you don't mind please use a JSON parser, like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). futher see this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326169/which-is-the-best-way-to-parse-json-data-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Iterator<String> iter = errors.keys();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iter.next();
                        Log.e("key",key);
                        JSONObject object = errors.getJSONObject(key);
                        //this object contains the values within a single key.
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [keys()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) iterator to iterate over all the properties.

```
for(Iterator<String> iter = errors.keys();iter.hasNext();) {
    String key = iter.next();
        ...
}
```

Comment: I did this to get the value: `Object value = errors.get(key); System.out.println(value);`, but I get the output with brackets and quotes: `["First"]`. Why?

Comment: Try to print key like : System.out.println(key);